# Does kendo provide panning icons like carousel to pan a chart?

Tags: html, angular, kendo-ui

I have a chart with data greater than the width of the chart. The data is shown for 6 hours and for the rest, the user needs to pan or drag the chart. I want to provide two buttons as shown in the image and on clicking them, I want to display the next or previous 6 hrs data. Is there a built in functionality that kendo provides for this because i couldn't find any.[image: Chart]

Comment: Are you using the Kendo Angular Chart component or the Kendo jQuery Chart widget?

Comment: Anuglar chart component